# Database design for point in bounding box

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I need to design a database which contains a table of cities which supports only a single query - given a point, return the city (or cities) which it falls in. I have the bounding box for each city.

I've looked into mysql spatial indexing, but most discussion I've seen of spatial indexing involves the inverse question - given a bounding box, return the set of entries which have a POINT column which falls within the bounding box, which they are able to do using MBRWITHIN to obtain.

What should the column look like to store the city bounding box to fully take advantage of mysql's spatial-indexing, multiple POINT columns? POLYGON? And what does the query look like.

Comment: How are your bounding boxes defined?

Comment: I have access to minlat, maxlat, minlon, maxlon, but of course I can convert the bounding boxes to any format necessary or convenient to store as a database column.

Comment: Dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173007/mysql-database-for-storing-city-bounding-boxes-and-names